# Why does Windows Task Manager show two ethernet connections with different throughputs if all my traffic is routed through the VPN?

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, task-manager

I am running Windows 10. I have a VPN installed, through which - as I understand it - all my internet traffic is routed through at a system / OS level.

When I look at Task Manager, I can see two ethernet adapters:

- Mullvad (my VPN)
- Local Area Connection / Intel Ethernet Connection I217 (which I assume is my motherboard's ethernet port)

If all my traffic goes through the VPN, I'd expect the throughput for both of these adapters to be identical. So, if Mullvad VPN is sending 15Kbps, the Intel adapter is also sending 15Kbps. In my head the simplified flow of traffic is: browser to Mullvad to Local Area Connection to internet.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/89TGs.png]

**Question:**

If you look at the above image, you can see the send and receive rate for the two adapters is different. The VPN's adapter is always lower.

Why?

Comment: The physical adapter will be a little more active, because it will carry the data that forms the VPN tunnel itself, in addition to the data passing through it. I can't see your image but is the difference between large or small? are there other devices on your LAN, and have you configured the VPN client to route all traffic through the default gateway on the remote network?

Comment: @FrankThomas The difference is significant (+16kbit/s / +200% up, +40kbit/s / +6% down), but I think this is the correct answer anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The throughput rates fluctuate when transmitting.

You are seeing the throughput of these two adapters, but not from the
same microsecond.

The throughput data, as all performance markers, is kept in the
registry.
But only one task may update the registry at any given time.

You have two adapters, each with its own driver, and each driver
updates its own performance data in the registry.
Because one needs to wait for the other to access the registry,
the sampling is not from the same microsecond.

In addition, to get these two performance numbers requires two reads
from the registry by the Task Manager. This means, again, that the
numbers are not from the same microsecond.

Because of these two offsets, it's unlikely that the two numbers will
be identical.

Answer (score 0):

Open Control Panel, Network and Sharing Center, Change Adapter Settings and you will see Physical Adapters and VPN adapters.  I see this here on my own machine.

So what you are seeing in Task Manager, Performance are these Adapters. I see this here in my own machine.

Your adapters in Task Manager will show traffic related to that adapter. If you have split tunnel allowed or local traffic on the other network adapter it will show up that way.

So all is normal and the way it is designed to be.

Comment: But my question is about the throughput rates - why are they different? I understand that there's two adapters, but if all traffic goes through the VPN then why isn't the send/receive rate identical in both?

Comment: Same thing. Your adapters will show traffic. I added that piece to my answer.